# Multi-value parameter using AND logic instead of OR

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

My report uses a multi-value parameter string to search through a block of text. We want the ability to only return results that meet all the values entered for this string. For example: Only return rows that have "Biopsy", "Prostate", AND "Lateral" values.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: show us your query. In that cases I usually use NVL function

Comment: I'm using a command object and have the following code in my WHERE clause: 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(RESULTS.COMMENT, '{?Comment}', 'i')
What I'm trying to do is only return the records that match all string values entered for parameter {?comment} meaning if the user enter " "Biopsy" "Prostate" "Lateral" values then i want each record to match all three of those values. Currently the report pulls values based on only one of the string values match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if crystal report accepts that condition (REGEXP_LIKE). Btw... You have to send the parameters one by one, for example:

```
Dim p As New Report
p.parameter1 = txtParameter1.Text
p.parameter2 = txtParameter2.Text
p.parameter3 = txtParameter3.Text
p.show()
```

Then in report

```
Public parameter1 As String
Public parameter2 As String
Public parameter3 As String

If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter1) Then
    "report-object".SetParameterValue("Parameter in Query", "'%'")
Else
    "report-object".SetParameterValue("Parameter in Query", "'" + parameter1 + "%'")
End If
.
.
```

I usually use this code for that.. and well in your command object, you only need a simple AND to match the parameters.

Comment: Hi Krum, Thanks for your response. In your example does this mean i would need multiple parameters? is it possible to link paramter1, parameter2 and parameter3 to one single parameter that the user will see?

Comment: Do you mean to see only in the report? or when the user have to "insert or choose" the parameters in the application?

Comment: I want the user to only see one parameter hopefully a Multi value string parameter.... This will allow them to enter several strings and return records based on the values they entered. So if they entered "Biopsy" "Prostate" then every row returned should have both of those values. They are searching through a big block of text so they are hoping they can narrow down there results.Im fairly new to crystal reports so i will apologize in advance

Comment: The example before works if you have an exact number of parameters, but if you have a "not defined" number of parameters, you have to solve that first

Comment: Any suggestions how I can define the parameter? I wasn't sure if this is possible in Crystal reports and this is way out of my area of expertise.

Comment: You have to block the user to only choose "N" numbers of parameters, then work in base of that number. We need more information about how the user are inserting the parameter.